# Display more than one fields using content search webpart

Tags: web-part, content-search-web-part

I need to show more than one field from particular list using content search web part. Please provide me the steps or any reference links for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good start: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_quick_reads/archive/2013/08/02/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-1.aspx

The writer explains what Display Templates are, how they work, and how you can add your own or edit already existing ones to your needs.